# What type of errors actually happen with mySQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a web-based application using mySQL, and I've used it in the past. I've never seen a mySQL error other then something during the development process -- ie. poorly formed selects -- but once its 'working' what kind of errors are there?

I've never seen an insert or select fail - can they? If the syntax is correct, why would they?

I'm mostly asking this with an eye toward figuring out what to do if an error actually does occour. If an insert/update fails, do I sleep a second and try again? How about a select? How many times before just giving up?

EDIT:
Maybe I asked this poorly, what I'm looking for is "How should I handle mySQL errors if and when they occour?". In every sample I've ever seen its to just die -- in a public application that seems very ugly. Is it worth retrying the command in a few seconds and then giving a error to the user and emailing the admin? Or just accept that a fatal error won't get fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could be something as simple as someone shutting down the MySQL server.
There might be limits set on the MySQL server, e.g. [MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-resources.html).
There can be errors or timeouts where the server drops the connection to the client (the popular [CR_SERVER_LOST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/error-messages-client.html#error_cr_server_lost)).
The data (file) may be corrupt which you may notice not until a query on the database/table runs.
Your test environment may have never run into a "packet too large" situation but then your production server does.
And many, many more... Have a read of http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/problems.html

Comment: I think I asked my original question poorly, maybe I'll try again when I'm closer to working on the project I was concerned with. Accepting this answer as it was valuable. :)

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few examples of errors that can occur even with SQL statements that are syntactically correct and which may work in your development environment:

- [Duplicate key violation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/constraint-primary-key.html) from an `INSERT` or `UPDATE`.  That is, a `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE KEY` prevents you from setting a column to the same value in another row.  Sleeping is not likely to fix this, you need to change the values you're inserting/updating.
- [Constraint violations](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/constraint-invalid-data.html) such as unsatisfied [foreign key](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) references or setting a `NOT NULL` column to NULL.  You need to insert/update using values that do not violate the constraints.  Deleting a row that has foreign key dependencies results in an error unless you defined cascading behavior in the FK constraint declaration.  Also it's an error to insert or update using a value that's out of range for a column's data type.
- [SQL privileges](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privilege-system.html) can restrict the operations you can perform.
- `SELECT` may give an error if you generate queries dynamically with your application code, and the query it generates is flawed.
- A query that worked before may give an error if someone changes the MySQL [`SQL MODE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-sql-mode.html) to be more strict.  For example, some implicit data type conversions or permissive enforcement of the Single-Value Rule in `GROUP BY` queries may fail.

Answer (score 0):

This would all depend on how you coded your project. Whether or not a select can fail will be a matter of how you're performing your selects in your code. Did you sanitize data properly?  Because this is regarding MySQL and PHP, it brings in questions about your server, configurations, environment, etc.

There are many routes for potential problems. This question really cannot be answered without first knowing how you set it all up to begin with. Others may include too many open connections, queries lasting for too long, cache-limits, dead-locks, etc. The potential-issues are too many to list here exhaustively.

Perhaps you should return with more specific questions about how to avoid sql-injections, sanitize data, handle complicated queries, etc. The community here would be quick to offer quality responses I'm sure.

Comment: I'm already familiar with all the practices you mentioned; I untaint any incomming data, and use mysql_real_escape_string on user data. I'm not talking about a query failing because the query is wrong. I'm talking about something failing because of a database problem.

I'm just not sure if that ever happens.

Comment: Erik, see the latter part of my first paragraph. There are *many* things that can go wrong, considering all of the details of your environment, setup, configuration, etc. It's not practical to list them.